# How to split a comma-delimited line from a file into variables in C?

Tags: c, file

If I have a file with one line containing `12,1`, how do I split the numbers and put them into 2 variables?  For example, variable `a` would get `12` and another variable `b` would get `1` .

Comment: `int a, b; fscanf(fp, "%d , %d", &a, &b);`

Comment: Can you post the code for reading the file, and where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First approach:

We use [fscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) and we put the format we expect the file to have. We loop, until the return value of the function is less than the numbers we expect to read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  if ((fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  { /* Open source file. */
    perror("fopen source-file");
    return 1;
  }
  int a, b;
  while(fscanf(fp, "%d,%d", &a, &b) == 2)
  {
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Second approach:

We read with [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) into a buffer and then we split with the help of [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), using the delimiter (comma in this case).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define bufSize 1024

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[bufSize];
  if ((fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  { /* Open source file. */
    perror("fopen source-file");
    return 1;
  }
  char* pch;
  int a, b, i;
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL)
  {
    i = 0;
    // eat newline
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    pch = strtok (buf,",");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
      // read first number
      if(!i++)
        a = atoi(pch);
      else // read second number
        b = atoi(pch);
      pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

The code is based in my example [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/copy-files-c/).

---

Both examples assume we have test.txt as this:

```
1,2
3,4
```

PS - Make sure you show some effort next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open the file and parse the file by pairs.

```
int a, b;
freopen("input_file", "r", stdin);
while(scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b) == 2)
{   // do sth with a, b
}
```

Comment: How does this answer improves the one solution I have already shown?